# Trouble understanding this 'simple' circuit

Tags: capacitor, diodes

I've been having trouble understanding this circuit, which is used in a larger circuit but this is the section which I can't wrap my head around.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Valve7+ is always at +24V and when valve7 is high, Q10 becomes short circuit which pulls Valve7- down to 0V which means the valve has 24V across it. I think that part is ok.

Now the other case is where I get confused, Valve7 is low, Q10 is open, Valve7+ is still +24V but now Valve7- is also +24V which means the valve has 0V across it.

How does Valve7- become +24V? Does current flow through C27 and loop through D8 eventually making the two lines equipotential?

What exactly is the purpose of D8?

I'm confused by the mechanism of having 0V across Valve7+/-.

Thanks

Comment: The current flows through the valve itself.

Comment: What are 'Valve7-' and 'Valve7+' connected to?  If it is in anyway inductive then D8 allows the voltage to momentarily reverse since any inductance wants current to keep flowing.  Without D8 the voltage on the drain of Q10 may raise until Q10 is damaged.

Comment: It is a valve and as peufeu mentioned it is connected via an electromagnet in the valve. Thanks for clarifying about the diode, it didn't make sense to me that there would be a current though D8 in normal operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that when Q10 is open, the valve turns off.  It does this by not providing a path to ground.  VALVE7- goes to +24V by leakage through C27 and D8 (assuming no valve is attached).  If the valve is attached, the entire thing is at +24V relative to ground.

The leakage through C27 and D8 shouldn't be much.  Enough to see the voltage, but if you shorted it, there would be so little current you probably couldn't measure it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about leakage, I was able to observe a voltage on Valve7- without the valve attached. I couldn't understand why there would be a current, it makes sense that there isn't! I feel a bit silly how simple it was.

Answer (score 1):

> How does Valve7- become +24V?

When the FET turns OFF, both VALVE pins are connected by the electromagnet inside the valve, which is just a coil of wire. So when no current is flowing in it, it will act like a low value resistor. So both valve pins will be at the same voltage.

Note that the cap and both ferrite beads are most likely to filter out voltage/current spikes and prevent emission of electromagnetic interference when the FET turns off.

Comment: Thanks for the info that there is an electromagnet inside the valve, that helped with understanding the purpose of D8 in the circuit, but when the valve is not connected the voltage is still observable I think it's due to leakage as evildemonic has answered.